# How do I get a column type "date" inserted into FULLTEXT in a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, select

I am making a control panel for administrators on my site that is a search function. When you enter a name it pulls the users first name,last name, email and password. When I tried to insert `Birthday` into the FULLTEXT to include it in the search, it is not on the drop down. I think because its type is 'date'. Is there a way around that? Also, status is showing up in the drop down but won't display when I put it in the match/search query. The only difference is that it has a default status of pending.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html):

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

Comment: Gotcha. so how do I make dates searchable?

Comment: Well the DATE format isn't free-form, it's strictly structured.  Consequently, you can have people choose values from pulldowns rather than typing in a textbox.